# Loading Wordpress styles

Tags: wordpress

No Matter what I do I cannot get the styles to load from the function. The page goes blank or the styles don't change. I have a folder called assets in the same level as style.css

```
function pbo_theme_assets() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'acf', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/acf.css' ) );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pbo_theme_assets' );
```

Comment: Did you check the generated HTML? Does the tag appear in the head?

Comment: The blank page could be the result of the superfluous closing bracket at the end of your`wp_enqueue_style()` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have extra closing bracket on line 2

```
function pbo_theme_assets() {
    wp_enqueue_style('acf',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/css/acf.css');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pbo_theme_assets' );
```

except that everything matches wp standards

Comment: Thanks I fixed that. I checked the source code and I have advanced custom fields plugin and it is somehow changing the path to my stylesheet